# Best practice to show that a function parameter is (or is not) intended to be modified

Tags: c#, function, coding-style, parameters

Function parameters tend to have different purposes : in most case they are just readonly indications used by the internal logic to produce a result/effect, but sometimes they are modified by the calling function (initialisation function, sorting algorithm etc).

I was wondering if there is a best practice to show in the code that the function is going to modify a parameter (apart from writing a comment above stating this explicitly)? Like a widely recognized coding convention.

With C++ I use the 'const' keyword for every parameter which is not going to be modified by the function, but C# does not allow const or 'readonly' to be used that way. And a lack of 'const' does not really mean that the parameter is intended to be updated by the function anyway.

Thanks

Comment: Usually I use [in] and [out] in comments before a function to indicate whether a parameter will be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in C# valued-type parameters (and strings, due to immutability) are "const" by default, unless you explicitly mark them with `out` or `ref` keywords. As for reference types function can only modify object that the parameter refers to, not the reference itself.

Moreover, those `out` and `ref` keywords are hints for compiler, that analyzes the flow of code and dissallows use of "uninitlized" variables. So. i.e. if you declare method:

```
void DoSomething(int i) { ... }
```

and then try calling it from the following code:

```
int x;
DoSomething(x);
```

the compiler will disallow, as `x` will be uninitialized at the time of call. On the other hand:

```
void DoSomething(out int i) { ... i = 10; ... }
```

the following call is now allowed:

```
int x;
DoSomething(out x);
```

as compiler now knows that `DoSomething` is going to initialize x. Notice, that `DoSomething` won't compile unless it containts a statament, that assigns some value to `i` parameter.

Comment: Thank you Kuba, but your answer covers the technical aspect of parameters modification, whereas my question concerns the development pratices.

To be more precise : I'm currently writing interfaces in a project, which will be used by other developpers to implement their own classes. In one of these interfaces, there's a function `foo(LinkedList<...> data)`.

How can I show that the linked list is intended to be modified by the function. Of course I can add a comment saying "This function will have to add elements to the list...", bu I was wondering if there is another common pratice.

Comment: OK, but there is no such an established practice in C# world, or at least none I've ever heard of. As I said, value-types are always read-only, and reference-types (except string) are always changeable. I.e. very common Array.Sort (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) sorts (modifies content of) provided Array parameter, but it is in no way indicated.